# Why can’t we check if an index appears in a slice object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice, contains

In basic use, a [slice object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) represents a subset of the integer indices of a sequence.  Why can’t I test whether an index is a member of that subset with `in`?  It could be constant-time, analogously to the corresponding operation on a (Python 3) [`range` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Answer (score 0):

Because even basic slices support negative indexes, checking for containment requires knowing the **length** of the sequence.  You can supply that length with `range`:

```
so=slice(b,e,s)
r=range(n)[so]
if i in r: # ...
```

`xrange` in Python 2 does not support the slicing (or the constant-time containment check).